# How can I use alternative credentials to write a registry key?

Tags: windows, powershell, registry, credentials

The script I am authoring needs to query a reg key (done), connect to a webservice via a proxy (done) and then set a registry key in HKLM.

We are attempting to adapt a script to store the warranty end date of Dell machines in the registry. The script needs to get out through our proxies, and by chance I noticed that PowerShell respects the IE Proxy settings (even using a PAC file) by default, which is great! Unfortunately, we have another requirement - the script must write into HKLM, which only administrators can do.

I tried using the `New-Item` cmdlet and the `-Credential` as per the information on technet, but it doesn't.

> The provider does not support the use of credentials. Perform the
>   operation again without specifying credentials."

I found [this thread](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/scriptcenter/en-US/79a923d2-8924-4133-825a-46346c493758/using-newitem-with-credentials?forum=ITCG), which suggests mapping a new PSDrive with a credential. This, however, throws the same error.

Is there any way in PowerShell I can write into HKLM using alternative credentials?

Comment: Anything reason you can't run the script as an Administrator? You have to elevate to those permissions anyway to write the key so why not do if for the whole run?

Comment: The Admin accounts we have, and the local admin account can't get out via the proxy so would need another alternative credential for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are going to tackle this in a different way, using a GPO to give user's permissions to the keys I want to write to.

This seems to a be a strange shortcoming in Powershell.

Answer (score 0):

If you have [PS Remoting](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff700227.aspx) enabled on the host, you can run a command via [`Invoke-Command`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849719.aspx):

```psh
$key   = 'HKLM:\Some\Subkey'
$value = 'ValueName'
$type  = 'String'
$data  = 'foobar'

$cred  = Get-Credential

Invoke-Command -Computer $env:COMPUTERNAME -ScriptBlock {
  New-ItemProperty -Path $args[0] -Name $args[1] -Type $args[2] -Value $args[3]
} -ArgumentList $key, $value, $type, $data -Credential $cred
```

Comment: Thanks Ansgar - I want to deploy this script via SCCM in order to capture all machines as and when they came online. We are thinking maybe to create a GPO and give users access to the specific key we want to write. We want to write a specific Key in the registry to stay in-line with other regions in our business who use a script to do the same for different manufacturers (HP and Lenovo) and use SCCM hardware inventory to capture the key.

Comment: This will hang on systems that don't have the proper service running on the remote host

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$key   = 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Citrix\Ica\Session'
$value = 'ClientAddress'
$type  = 'String'
$data  = '10.11.19.35'

$secpasswd =  “your-password” | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force 
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential (“domain\your-username”, $secpasswd) 

$cmd = "New-ItemProperty -Path $key -Name $value -Type $type -Value $data"

$pinfo = New-Object System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
$pinfo.FileName = "C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Powershell.exe"
$pinfo.RedirectStandardError = $true
$pinfo.RedirectStandardOutput = $true
$pinfo.UseShellExecute = $false
$pinfo.Arguments = "-Command $cmd"
$pinfo.Username = $credential.username
$pinfo.Password = $credential.password
$p = New-Object System.Diagnostics.Process
$p.StartInfo = $pinfo
$p.Start() | Out-Null
$p.WaitForExit()
$stdout = $p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()
$stderr = $p.StandardError.ReadToEnd()
Write-Host "stdout: $stdout"
Write-Host "stderr: $stderr"
Write-Host "exit code: " + $p.ExitCode
```